# peer node start => Cannot dial to 0.0.0.0:7050, because of grpc: timed out when dialing

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Can someone suggest how to resolve error, Cannot dial to 0.0.0.0:7050, because of grpc: timed out when dialing, when running peer node start.

> 2017-01-01 16:48:24.391 UTC [committer] initDeliver -> ERRO 097 Cannot dial to 0.0.0.0:7050, because of grpc: timed out when dialing
>   2017-01-01 16:48:24.392 UTC [committer] startDeliver -> ERRO 098 Can't initiate deliver protocol [grpc: timed out when dialing]

I am also getting error when running :

```
peer chaincode deploy -n mycc -c '{"Args": ["init", "a","100", "b", "200"]}'
```

> Error: Error getting broadcast client: Error connecting to 0.0.0.0:7050 due to grpc: timed out when dialing

Comment: which version of fabric are you using? 0.6 or 1.0 preview?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using the wrong port for grpc. **7050** is the REST port for the peer. The default grpc port is **7051**.

Comment: Thanks for answering, where can I adjust the port number ?